# Creating an annotation list using time stamps

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series, pytorch

I have ECG data of length 230897 and sampling frequency=100hz. I would like to create an annotation list (of length 230897) corresponding to the timestamps and duration (in seconds) of the arrhythmia event (sequence of 1's):

```
timestamps                                  duration
2014-09-10T22:10:20.000000000                 3.5
2014-09-10T23:10:10.000000000                 4
2014-09-10T23:50:20.000000000                 6
```

FOr example: the annotation list should be of length 230897 and at '2014-09-10T22:10:20.000000000' there should be 1's for 3.5 seconds; at'2014-09-10T23:10:10.000000000' 1's for 4 seconds and so on. This is what I have tried so far and unfortunately, it is not working:

```
start_time= '2014-09-10T21:01:10.000000000'
data_length=230897
annot_list = np.zeros(data_length)

prev=0, fs=100
for t in timestamps:
        time_diff = t - prev
        seconds = time_diff.astype('timedelta64[s]').astype(np.int32)
        total_cov = seconds*fs
        i1 = i0 + total_cov
        i0, i1 = int(i0), int(i1)
        annot_list[i0:i1] = 1.0
        i0 = i1
        prev = t
```

Can someone please help me here?

Comment: Would you mind providing expected `annot_list` please, just first few elements

Comment: 00001111110000011111000... until the length of the data (data_length)....                    
at 2014-09-10T22:10:20.000000000, there should be 1's of duration 3.5 seconds,       at 2014-09-10T23:10:10.000000000 1's of 4s and so on.

Comment: I'm really finding it hard to map 6 ones with 3.5 seconds and 5 ones with 4 seconds. Please be somewhat more descriptive. How many total timestamps are there? If its 230897 then how can you expect more than one value for single index without converting it to a list or something.

Comment: @YashvanderBamel : Initially annot_list is an array of zeros of shape (230897,1).  Then at each timestamp (which is the start time of the event), there should be 1's of the corresponding duration. I just gave an example but there are 350 1's (3.5 secondsx100Hz) and 400 1's (4x100Hz) and so on. In the code, start_time is the start time of the ECG recording.

Comment: Are you sure about your start time? The time difference in 10th of ms (to respect your 100Hz frequency) between your first time stamp and the start time is more than 400 000, which is bigger than the size of your array.

Comment: @Lescurel: yes sorry about that. It should be 2308970

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your data looks like that:

```
timestamps = [np.datetime64("2014-09-10T22:10:20.000000000"),
    np.datetime64("2014-09-10T23:10:10.000000000"),
    np.datetime64("2014-09-10T23:50:20.000000000")]

durations = [3.5,4,6]
```

Then, you can simply iterate over your list and caluclate your start index and your stop index from your start time, your timestamp and your duration, like so:

```
start_time = np.datetime64("2014-09-10T21:01:10.000000000")
data_length = 2308970
annot_list = np.zeros(data_length)
freq = 100

for timestamp, duration in zip(timestamps, durations):
    time_from_start = int(
        freq * (np.timedelta64(timestamp - start_time, "s").astype("float32"))
    )
    duration = int(freq * duration)
    annot_list[time_from_start : time_from_start + duration] = 1
```